# Non-uniform byte initialization

Tags: c++, enums, list-initialization, uniform-initialization, std-byte

Is there a reason, simple enough to explain to non language lawyers, why the initializations commented out fail to compile while the first one succeeds?

```
#include <cstddef>

void test() {
  std::byte a{42};
  //std::byte b = {42};
  //std::byte c[]{48, 49};
}
```

Code on https://godbolt.org/z/nGfzjnh4f

---

The error is:

```
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'std::byte' with an rvalue of type 'int'
```

Comment: Please show us the *failing* code, and the errors you get in the question itself. To make the question self-contained.

Comment: [A numeric value n can be converted to a byte value using std::byte{n}, due to C++17 **relaxed enum class initialization rules**.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `std::byte` is an `enum class` and `std::byte b = {42}` is not **direct-list-initialization** which is the only syntax allowed here since it uses C++17's  [relaxed enum class initialization rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#enum_relaxed_init_cpp17):

> **An enumeration can be initialized from an integer without a cast, using list initialization, if all of the following are true**:
>
> - The initialization is **direct-list-initialization**.
> - The initializer list has only a single element.
> - The enumeration is either scoped or unscoped with underlying type fixed.
> - The conversion is non-narrowing.

(emphasis mine)

And since `std::byte b = {42}` doesn't satisfy the first bullet requirement, we get the mentioned error.

Comment: So direct-list-init is now stronger than direct-copy-init in some aspects. Damn.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, C++ and its initialization rules!